# XCode C++: Linker command failed with exit code 1 library not found for -lboost_regex

Tags: c++, xcode, boost, linker, boost-regex

{There are many possible duplicates for Linker command related problems I read all of them I could find but none helped me so I am posting a new question.}

My build is failing with following Linker message:
`ld: library not found for -lboost_regex
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`.

Though I have supplied boost-regex static library.

**EDIT:** I have added `libboost_regex.a` in `Build Phases->Link Binary With Library`

`Ld` command executed by `XCode` is as following.

`Ld /Applications/Adobe\ InDesign\ CC\ 2017/Plug-Ins/AdWrks-CC17.v1.1.InDesignPlugin/Versions/A/AdWrks-CC17.v1.1 normal x86_64
    cd /Users/apple/SDKs/CS12SDK/build/mac/prj
    export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.11
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch x86_64 -dynamiclib -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk -L/Applications/Adobe\ InDesign\ CC\ 2017/Plug-Ins -L../../../build/mac/release_cocoa64/packagefolder/contents/macos/libs -L/Users/apple/SDKs/CS12SDK/build/mac/prj/../../../.. -L/Users/apple/SDKs/CS12SDK/build/mac/prj/../../../source/sdksamples/AdWorks -F/Applications/Adobe\ InDesign\ CC\ 2017/Plug-Ins -F../../../build/mac/release_cocoa64/packagefolder/contents/macos -F../../../build/mac/release_cocoa64/packagefolder/contents/Frameworks -filelist /Users/apple/SDKs/CS12SDK/build/mac/prj/build/AdWrks-CC17.build/Default/Release_Cocoa64.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AdWrks-CC17.v1.1.LinkFileList -install_name ./AdWrks-CC17.v1.1.InDesignPlugin/Versions/A/AdWrks-CC17.v1.1 -mmacosx-version-min=10.11 -dead_strip -no_dead_strip_inits_and_terms -Wl,-executable_path -Wl,../../../build/mac/Release_Cocoa64/packagefolder/contents/macos/ -stdlib=libc++ -lboost_regex-mt -lboost_regex-mt -lboost_regex -lcrypto.0.9.8 -lxerces-c-3.1 -lxerces-c.28 -lz.1.2.5 -framework InDesignModelAndUI -lxerces-c.28 -lboost_regex-mt -lPublicPlugIn -single_module -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/apple/SDKs/CS12SDK/build/mac/prj/build/AdWrks-CC17.build/Default/Release_Cocoa64.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AdWrks-CC17.v1.1_dependency_info.dat -o /Applications/Adobe\ InDesign\ CC\ 2017/Plug-Ins/AdWrks-CC17.v1.1.InDesignPlugin/Versions/A/AdWrks-CC17.v1.1`

What could be the reason? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: "Though I have supplied boost-regex static library."
Edit your question to show us what you mean by "supplying" it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem. I used dynamic library for boost-regex instead of static library. It solved my problem.